# ScalaMock a method with two parameter groups

Tags: scala, scalamock

How exactly should I mock something like this (the post method of Play's WSRequest from the WS library):

```
def post[T](body: T)(implicit wrt: Writeable[T], ct: ContentTypeOf[T]): Future[WSResponse]
```

I've read through the [ScalaMock page about this](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/advanced_topics/) and I'm not having any success.

Can it also be stubbed? I'm trying this with no luck:

```
(mockRequest.post[String] (_ : String)(_ : Writeable[String], _: ContentTypeOf[String])).when(*,*,*).returns(Future.successful(mockResponse))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
(mockRequest.post(_ : String)(_ : Writeable[String], _: ContentTypeOf[String])).expects(*,*,*).returning(Future.successful(mockResponse))
```